# How to keep only occurrences that end with a specific letter?

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I would like to keep all occurrences which end only with a specific letter (lets say "a") from a string. I am not dealing with a vector composed of different elements but rather a string whose occurrences are separated by spaces.

Here are the data:

```
 have="5a 4a 8a 10a 3a 5m 10m 7a 8p 11s 5s 4h 24h"
 want="5a 4a 8a 10a 3a 7a"
```

Here are some codes:

```
gsub("([A-Z]|[0-9])([m|p|h|s])","", have)
gsub("\\w+m|p|h|s *", "", have)
```

After applying one of these gsub codes, I get 2 types of info (alphanumeric followed by "a" and purely figures).

But I still need to clean so I get only the occurrences ending with "a". Whould you have any idea?

Comment: Try this pattern  `\b\da\b` See https://regex101.com/r/JRJXdg/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use this pattern and replace with an empty string:

```
[ ]?[a-z0-9]+[mphs]
```

- `[ ]?` Optional space (the square brackets are only for clarity)
- `[a-z0-9]+` Character class, match 1+ times a-z 0-9
- `[mphs]` Character class, match m, p h or s

For example

```
have="5a 4a 8a 10a 3a 5m 10m 7a 8p 11s 5s 4h 24h"
gsub(" ?[a-z0-9]+[mphs]","", have)
```

Result

```
[1] "5a 4a 8a 10a 3a 7a"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wtd0Xj/2) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/YUs3L5)

Perhaps you could match them instead:

```
\b\da\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `\d` a digit
- `a` match a
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wtd0Xj/1)

Note that in the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[m|p|h|s]` the `|` does not mean `or` but a `|` char and can also be written as `[mphs|]`.

Comment: Thanks! From which resource can I learn to do that? How the hell did you end up with " ?[a-z0-9]+[mphs]"???

Comment: @aguiot That is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match 1+ times any of the listed.  The character class does not have an or `|`. You could write it as `[mphs|]` and it will also match a pipe `|`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
  trimws(gsub("([A-Z]|[0-9]{1,})([b-z])","",have))
[1] "5a 4a 8a 10a 3a   7a"
```

To remove the extra space:

```
gsub("\\s{2,}"," ",
      trimws(gsub("([A-Z]|[0-9]{1,})([b-z])","",have)))
#[1] "5a 4a 8a 10a 3a 7a"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split it into words, use `grep` to identify the words ending in a, then paste them back together.

```
Words = strsplit(have, "\\W+")[[1]]
paste(grep("a$", Words, value=T), collapse=" ")
[1] "5a 4a 8a 10a 3a 7a"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, much longer but easier regexp, turn it into a vector and then turn it back to a string.

```
have_string <- "5a 4a 8a 10a 3a 5m 10m 7a 8p 11s 5s 4h 24h"
have_vector <- unlist(strsplit(have_string," "))
library(stringr)
want_vector <- have_vector[str_detect(have_vector, ".*?a$")]
want_string <- paste(want_vector, sep = " ", collapse = " ")
```